# Edittext cursor breaks in marshmallow rtl supported layout

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

I am facing weird issue in marshmallow.
When locale is `ar` and I type english text then cursor in edittext breaks

Refer screenshot

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="left|start"
    android:hint="@string/app_name"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textDirection="locale">
    <requestFocus/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it using below..

In your xml layout, for edit text field add this--> `android:textDirection="anyRtl"`

Here, "editText" is your view of edit text field. i.e,

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

Then programatically add text watcher for that edit text.

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    editText.setSelection(s.length()); // this line is very important for setting cursor position
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

setting `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"` works for me

Comment: i have the same problem but unfortunately this does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this two cursor/caret thing have something to do with how Android manages two different direction languages (RTL and LTR). Like this primary and secondary caret picture: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/39639/81811

I think you should also note you gravity. You are forcing both left and start. On a LTR language the start of the text is on left, but when you use Arabic, you are saying you want the gravity both at left and right (since start of a RTL language is at the rightmost character).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also got same problem for rtl based locale. 
So I have made below properties to `EditText`

```
 android:textDirection="ltr"
 android:textAlignment="viewStart"
 android:gravity="start"
```

> Above properties have fixed two cursor problem

The above properties state that we have designed `EditText` to be  `left to right(ltr)`

one and text should start from `left i.e start`. 
So OS will reverse direction for `rtl locale`.

This works perfectly for arabic languages which have rtl

Comment: Your problem alone with `android:textDirection="ltr"` will work. But the answer expected was different for the question. This may be way out but not solution

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. below is my solution:

```
<EditText
       android:id="@+id/etCode"
       style="@style/CodeFieldEdittext"
       android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
       android:imeOptions="actionDone"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:text="" />
```

in styles.xml

```
<style name="CodeFieldEdittext">
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/code_blue_cursor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorFieldBg</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorFieldHint</item>
    </style>
```

cursor drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorFieldBg" />
</shape>
```